# I need to YARN outside of Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am thinking if I can use YARN without HDFS.

Is it possible to use YARN from outside of Hadoop? For cluster management purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use YARN without HDFS. You only not configuring or started HDFS services, and run applications without use HDFS API.

But, YARN is a part of Hadoop, you don't run YARN without download and configure Hadoop. Therefore, Install and configure Hadoop is, in general, install and configure HDFS and YARN (And other components, if you need them).